# Associate container datasources through jndi for spring boot war files in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, datasource, jndi

I'm looking for solutions to solve the following problem:

I'm using a single instance of a standalone Tomcat 8 container in which I deploy multiple web services as war files which are Spring Boot 1.3.1 based.

I defined 3 data source resources in Tomcat's context.xml:

```
<Resource name="DBResource1" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
      url="URL"
      username="USERNAME"
      password="PASSWORD"
        .......
  />
```

So I have 3 of these: DBResource1, DBResource2, DBResource3 each connecting to a different database with different credentials.

And I have 3 war files deployed in Tomcat's webapps directory: service1.war, service2.war, service3.war

Before having these separated data sources I used to have only one tomcat data source resource which was shared by all services and I used to reference it in the single .properties file which contained all the properties for the 3 services like this: 
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:com/env/jdbc/DBResource1

What are the possibilities for associating the jndi resources to the war files like this:

service1.war to use DBResource1

service2.war to use DBResource2

service3.war to use DBResource3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you know how to get a JNDI datasource from a Spring app, then get DBResource1 from the service1 app, DBResource2 from the service2 app, and DBResource3 from the service3 app. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: @JB Nizet  I just use one default spring boot property naming which is automatically used to create a bean that is injected, as far as i know it would be used by all services. I don't have anything programatically done so that the resources is picked up by a specific app. So if I declare 3 JNDI resources it would not know for which service to associate each with, right?

Comment: I don't understand anything to your explanation. Post the 3 pieces of code, from each of the 3 apps, used to get a DataSource.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to say... I don't have anything like that done. So that's what I'm looging for. As I stated in the question I used to have only one data source resource defined in tomcat which was used in all 3 services which did not have any reference or configuration for it. Only this property: spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:com/env/jdbc/DBResource and spring boot did all the magic. And now that I have 3 resources I'm looking for a way to inject each specifically.in each service. Do you understand now ?

Comment: So, you have spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/DBResource. That's code. And it's referring to an entry in the web.xml, that you can post too. Put the URL of the first datasource in the web.xml of the first webapp, the URL of the second datasource in the web.xml of the second webapp, and the URL of the third datasource in the web.xml of the third webapp.

Comment: spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/DBResource is a property defined in application.properties , it's not really code :) and it s refering to a resource defined in context.xml both aspects were stated in my question. I don't have any web.xml file in any app.

Comment: OK. So change the value of this property to java:comp/env/jdbc/DBResource1 in the first app, java:comp/env/jdbc/DBResource2 in the second app, and java:comp/env/jdbc/DBResource3 in the third app. What's the concrete problem?